# css and javascript scroll like iOS photo apps

Tags: javascript, css, ios, html

I want to know the technique name to scroll item like iOS photo apps , for example , when the user scroll his/her mouse scroll wheel in how fast or how long is consider as ONE scrolling action and then make a transition to another section of the web page.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

It is called kinetic or momentum scrolling.

It does not work on mouse wheel, because legacy Microsoft Windows mouse wheels are digital and do not provide required analog input to make the action smooth. On OSX you have analog mouse wheel on Magic Mouse, but this is not mapped out to Javascript APIs.

However, for drag and drop you can have something like this:

http://the-taylors.org/jquery.kinetic/